# Background thread and three-layer architecture

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is my Logic_Layer, and I want to send a specific date with some values, name, phone, type, and result to the GUI_Layer, where it has to been shown in a message box through a background worker.
The problem is that my logic_layer, does not get any information in the List. How to solve this?

```
List<Test_DTO> pReminder = new List<Test_DTO>();

public List<Person_DTO> Reminder(string name, string phone, string type, string resul)
{
    GetPersonFromDataLayer();
    foreach (Person_DTO person in personList)
    {
        foreach (Test_DTO test in person.TestListe)
        {
            if (DateTime.Parse(pr.ContactTime).Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                if (!pReminder.Contains(test))
                {
                    pReminder.Add(test);
                }
                personDTO.TestList = pReminder;
                personList.Add(personDTO);
            }
        }
    }
    return persList;
}
```

This is the GUI-Layer.

```
private void System_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = null;
    string phone = null;
    string type = null;
    string result = null;

    reminderThread = new Thread(() => logik.Reminder(name, phone, type, result));
    Reminder(name, phone, type, result);
    reminderThread.IsBackground = true;
    reminderThread.Start();
}

public void Reminder(string name, string phone, string type, string result)
{
    personList = logik.Reminder(name, phone, type, result);
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Reminder!\nContact: " + navn + "\nPhone number: "
        + telefonnummer + "\n___________________________\nTest type: " + type + "\nResult: " + resultat);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: Well first of all you shouldn't use MessageBox from another thread (even if it works 99.9%). 2nd your function will be executed just once (then why a thread instead of a thread pool?). 3rd are you sure your logic returns something? Hard to say 'cause we don't know objects involved there

Comment: Ya, but the task is that the application shall further in a background task to handle reminders for contact with patients. These should be displayed in the GUI.
What should I then use instead a message box?
I'm a bit confused. Can you help me on the right way?

Comment: Do you want me to put the logic_layer method, in the data layer, because it have to return something, if not, anything will come to the GUI_layer.

Comment: For a background task you should use BackgroundWorker component. It'll run your code in a background thread and invoke UI notification when finished in the right UI thread (otherwise you have to do it by yourself with BeginInvoke). Start with [MSDN article about BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).